USRP B200 Mini GNU Radio Tx/Rx Switching
I am trying to build a GNU radio module/block using python that can trigger the Tx/Rx switching operation on the USRP B200.
I am getting the Packet in the form of a PDU from a TCP/IP connection, I process the bit stream and provide it to the UHD: USRP Sink block.
Here is a code I tried to implement to put the USRP into ATR_TX mode, but it is not working, I am probing the GPIO pins on the header using a oscilloscope.
import uhd
usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP()
gpio_bank = 'FP0'
gpio_mask = 0xFFF  # Apply to all GPIO pins
usrp.set_gpio_attr(gpio_bank, 'CTRL', gpio_mask, gpio_mask)
Configure ATR states
usrp.set_gpio_attr(gpio_bank, 'ATR_TX', gpio_mask, gpio_mask)  # TX state: All pins HIGH
usrp.set_gpio_attr(gpio_bank, 'ATR_RX', 0x000, gpio_mask)      # RX state: All pins LOW
usrp.set_gpio_attr(gpio_bank, 'ATR_0X', 0x000, gpio_mask)      # Idle state: All pins LOW
I tried to build another code, which senses the input and then tries to trigger the GPIO's, I still have no luck with that either. The second code is developed to have control over the time duration for which the switch is controlled.
import uhd
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr
class blk(gr.sync_block):
"""Python block to monitor input and control GPIO on USRP B200"""
def init(self,manual_control = True, manual_tx = True):
gr.sync_block.init(
self,
name='USRP GPIO Controller', # Block name
in_sig=[np.float32], # Input signal type
out_sig=None # No output
)
# Initialize the USRP device and GPIO
self.usrp = uhd.usrp.MultiUSRP()
self.usrp.set_gpio_attr("FP0", "DDR", 0xFF, 0xFF) # Set GPIO pins as output

# Track GPIO state (0 = RX, 1 = TX)
self.gpio_state = 0

self.manual_control = manual_control
self.manual_tx = manual_tx

def set_manual_control(self,enabled):
self.manual_control = enabled
printf(f"Manual Control enabled: {enabled}")
def set_manual_tx(self,tx_mode):
self.manual_tx = tx_mode
if self.manual_control:
if tx_mode:
self.set_tx_mode()
else:
self.set_rx_mode()
def set_tx_mode(self):
"""Set GPIO HIGH for TX mode."""
if self.gpio_state != 1: # Only switch if not already in TX mode
self.usrp.set_gpio_attr("FP0", "OUT", 0xFF, 0xFF) # Pin 0 HIGH
print("Switched to TX mode")
self.gpio_state = 1
def set_rx_mode(self):
"""Set GPIO LOW for RX mode."""
if self.gpio_state != 0: # Only switch if not already in RX mode
self.usrp.set_gpio_attr("FP0", "OUT", 0x00, 0xFF) # Pin 0 LOW
print("Switched to RX mode")
self.gpio_state = 0
def work(self, input_items, output_items):
"""Process input stream and toggle GPIO based on signal presence."""
in0 = input_items[0] # Get the input stream
if self.manual_control:
  if self.manual_tx:
    self.set_tx_mode()
  else:
    self.set_rx_mode()
else:
  if len(in0) > 0: # If there is input data (signal present)
    self.set_tx_mode() # Switch to TX mode
  else: # If no input data (idle)
    self.set_rx_mode() # Switch to RX mode

return len(in0) # Return number of processed samples

